# Unity editor gui, basic logic

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I've been programming in Unity for more than three years and I have always been bothered by the problem of public variables filling my inspector screen. After few hours of searching the internet, I've come across many in-depth editor GUI tutorials and demonstrations, but they never explained how to do what I want to do and that is to keep all my variables organized into lists.

Example: I want to create a public bool variable that when enabled in the editor opens up a list of new variables that a programmer/artist can interact with. Think of it as a parent object that has a bunch of children that only show up when the parent object is enabled.

Lately, I've been hearing about functions that only run when the editor is enabled and the game is not running so maybe that's the way to solve my problem. Right now I don't know where to look for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a custom inspector which is fully supported in Unity.

A good starting guide is here: [Building a Custom Inspector](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector)

And this answer below was provided [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/940691/custom-editor-show-variable-if-boolean-is-true.html)

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(YourScript))]
public class YourScriptEditor : Editor
{
 private bool AToggle = false;
 private YourScript _evCtrl = null;
 void OnEnable()
 {
     _evCtrl = (YourScript)target;
 }
 public override void OnInspectorGUI()
 {
     //blablabla
     GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
     GUILayout.Label("A Features", GUILayout.Width(70));
     AToggle = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(AToggle);
     GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
     if (AToggle)
     {
         GUILayout.Space(5);
         GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
         GUILayout.Label("This Var", GUILayout.Width(70));
         _evCtrl.ThisVar = EditorGUILayout.TextField(_evCtrl.ThisVar);
         GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
         GUILayout.Space(5);
         GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
         GUILayout.Label("And This One", GUILayout.Width(70));
         _evCtrl.AndThisOne = EditorGUILayout.TextField(_evCtrl.AndThisOne);
         GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
         GUILayout.Space(5);
         GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
         GUILayout.Label("And This Can Be Slider", GUILayout.Width(70));
         _evCtrl.AndThisCanBeSlider = EditorGUILayout.Slider(_evCtrl.AndThisCanBeSlider, 0f, 100f);
         GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
     }
     //blablabla
 }
}
```

Comment: I've watched Unity tutorial, it covers what I've asked, now it just the matter of getting familiar with the system. Thanks a lot!